# RU consumption of ARRAY_CONTAINS in cosmosdb query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Hi I am trying to understand Point Read vs Queries in Azure Cosmos DB
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/point-reads-versus-queries/

I have a query

```
   const querySpec: SqlQuerySpec = {
        query: 'select * from c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(@ids, c.id)',
        parameters: [{ name: '@Ids', value: ids }],
    };
```

My question is what would be the RU consumption of this query?  Since I am just comparing `id` , will it be `1` or higher?

I tried going through various articles but none gave me specific answer about what will be the RUs if I query specs with just id.

Comment: There's really no way for anyone to tell you the RU cost - you need to try it out and look at the resulting RU cost, which will vary based on number of indexed properties, number of partitions, etc. Also, using `id` when searching in an array is not the same as a point-read, since the array still needs to be searched, and invokes the query engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends. The cost of queries depends on your collection size, number of partitions and partition key, so it's hard to give a definitive conclusion on what is better.

A query will always use at minimum >2.3RU even when you query exactly on the id and partition key. While a point read will always be 1RU for documents <1KB.

However they scale differently; if you use the `ARRAY_CONTAINS` on the `id` you'll see that each extra document you add in the array will add less RU than a point read would. So if you query enough documents in the array (within reason)  will at some point cost less than doing separate point reads for each document. It also seems that queries handle very very large documents better as you can end up using less RU with a query opposed to a point read (not sure why).

Best way to test out what is better for your use case is to just test it out and see the results. For normal use cases you typically can pick whatever fits your functional needs best. Need one particular document? Use a point read. Need a set of documents? Use a query.

Comment: You said it will be 1RU for < 1KB. What about when document size is more than 100 MB? Is this documented anywhere by Microsoft?

Comment: The maximum size of a document is 2MB (with 16MB in preview for the MongoDB API). For any normal scenario you'll likely never get close to that limit and if you do you're probably doing something wrong like embedding a file into the JSON (a better solution would be a link to a blob storage for example). To give an indication a document of ~100KB costs a little less then 10RU to retrieve using a point read.

Comment: I was talking about the container size. Document size is not more than 1KB for me. Do you know how ARRAY_CONTAINS internally interpreted.  When I do like IN('ID') with id, it is consuming around 11RUs.

Comment: Container size doesn't really matter. The `id` property should be indexed allowing the query to use an index seek, which is constant and thus is not affected by the cardinality of the indexed property.